# AWS Athena creates indentation and moves values into wrong columns after partitions loads

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, partitioning, amazon-athena

I encountered the following problem:

1. I created a Hive table in an EMR cluster in HDFS without partitions
   and loaded a data to it.
2. I created another Hiva table based on the
       table from the paragraph#1 but with partitions from the datetime
       column: PARTITIONED BY (year STRING,month STRING,day STRING).
3. I loaded a data from the non partitioned table into partitioned table and get the valid result.
4. I created an Athena database and table with the same structure as Hive table.
5. I copied partitioned files from HDFS locally and by aws s3 sync transferred all files into S3 empty bucket. All files were transferred without error and with the same order as in Hive directory in HDFS.
6. I loaded partitions by MSCK REPAIR TABLE and didn't get any error in an output.

After that I found that many values got indentation, for example a value that need to be in the "IP" column was in "Operating_sys" column and etc.

My scripts are:

```
-- Hive tables

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;  
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cloudfront_logs_page_part 
    ( 
        log_DATE STRING,  
        user_id STRING, 
        page_path STRING, 
        referer STRING,
        tracking_referer STRING,
        medium STRING,
        campaign STRING,
        source STRING,
        visitor_id STRING,
        ip STRING,
        session_id STRING,
        operating_sys STRING,
        ad_id STRING,
        keyword STRING,
        user_agent STRING
    )
PARTITIONED BY
(
        `year` STRING,
        `month` STRING,
        `day` STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/admin/events_partitioned';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cloudfront_logs_event_part
    ( 
        log_DATE STRING, 
        user_id STRING, 
        category STRING, 
        action STRING, 
        label STRING, 
        value STRING,
        visitor_id STRING,
        ip STRING,
        session_id STRING,
        operating_sys STRING,
        extra_data_json STRING
    )
PARTITIONED BY
(
        `year` STRING,
        `month` STRING,
        `day` STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/admin/pages_partitioned';

INSERT INTO TABLE cloudfront_logs_page_part
PARTITION 
(
    `year`,
    `month`,
    `day`
)
SELECT
    log_DATE,
    user_id,
    page_path,
    referer,
    tracking_referer,
    medium, 
    campaign, 
    source,
    visitor_id,
    ip,
    session_id,
    operating_sys,
    ad_id,
    keyword,
    user_agent,
    year(log_DATE) as `year`,
    month(log_DATE) as `month`,
    day(log_DATE) as `day`
FROM
    cloudfront_logs_page;

INSERT INTO TABLE cloudfront_logs_event_part
PARTITION 
(
    `year`,
    `month`,
    `day`
)
SELECT
    log_DATE,
    user_id,
    category,
    action,
    label,
    value,
    visitor_id,
    ip,
    session_id,
    operating_sys,
    extra_data_json,
    year(log_DATE) as `year`,
    month(log_DATE) as `month`,
    day(log_DATE) as `day`
FROM
    cloudfront_logs_event;

-- Athena tables

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test
LOCATION 's3://...';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.cloudfront_logs_page_ath;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS powtoon_hive.cloudfront_logs_page_ath ( 
    log_DATE STRING,  
    user_id STRING, 
    page_path STRING, 
    referer STRING,
    tracking_referer STRING,
    medium STRING,
    campaign STRING,
    source STRING,
    visitor_id STRING,
    ip STRING,
    session_id STRING,
    operating_sys STRING,
    ad_id STRING,
    keyword STRING,
    user_agent STRING
)
PARTITIONED BY (`year` STRING,`month` STRING, `day` STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS   TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 's3://.../';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.cloudfront_logs_event_ath;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.cloudfront_logs_event_ath 
    ( 
        log_DATE STRING, 
        user_id STRING, 
        category STRING, 
        action STRING, 
        label STRING, 
        value STRING,
        visitor_id STRING,
        ip STRING,
        session_id STRING,
        operating_sys STRING,
        extra_data_json STRING
    )
PARTITIONED BY (`year` STRING,`month` STRING, `day` STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 's3://.../';
```

What can be wrong? Table structure? Athena metadata?

Comment: Side-note: It might be easier to convert to parquet format. See: [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html). Might also be cheaper/faster: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Comment: Do you think the better way is to convert Hive partitioned tables to a Parquet format and transfer to Parquet partitioned tables into Athena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to convert your raw files directly into a **partitioned Parquet columnar format**. This has the benefit of partitioning, columnar storage, predicate push-down and all those other fancy words.

See: [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)